# CakePHP: issues with different model and used table names

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm having a problem where I get an error saying,

```
Error: Database table catalog_product_entity for model CatalogProductEntity was not found.
```

I want the model `MagentoCatalogProductEntity` to use the table `catalog_product_entity`, but why is it looking for the model named after the table I defined, instead of the actual model name, `MagentoCatalogProductEntity`?

I have...

magento_catalog_product_entity.php

```
class MagentoCatalogProductEntity extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'MagentoCatalogProductEntity';
    public $useTable = 'catalog_product_entity';
    ...
}
```

magento_catalog_product_entity_controller.php

```
class MagentoCatalogProductEntityController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'MagentoCatalogProductEntity';
    ....
}
```

Note that this works, could it be some bug where if the model name and `$useTable` share similar names, it doesn't work properly?

test.php

```
class Test extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Test';
    public $useTable = 'catalog_product_entity';
    ...
}
```

EDIT 2013-06-12

I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the setup I provided above. I am currently just using the following.. I really want that "magento" prefix in the file and class names, but this will do for now.

catalog_product_entity.php

```
class CatalogProductEntity extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'CatalogProductEntity';
    public $useTable = 'catalog_product_entity';
    ...
}
```

catalog_product_entity_controller.php

```
class CatalogProductEntityController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'CatalogProductEntity';
    ....
}
```

Comment: if Cake is ignoring your `$useTable` property - it's because it's not loading the model class at all (the file is probably misnamed, or in the wrong place). You can check for this by verifying that the class of your CatalogProductEntity model is `AppModel` - or simply by putting a blatant php error in your model file and seeing that it doesn't break your app.

Comment: I've tried breaking the `magento_catalog_product_entity.php` and that gives an parse error, so it's definitely reading the file.. hm.. Note that I added a case, where `$useTable` works as intended, in the post.

Comment: Where? "Note that" your question is hard to understand e.g. `Error: Database table catalog_product_entities ... not found.` and `Note that for this example, table named catalog_product_entities exists` are contradictory and confusing.

Comment: You give an example model and controller, of which you say, "Note that this works", so why not just use that code, you don't explain why you can't?

Comment: I don't want to use a model or controller named `Test` or `tests`. In the "note that.." segment, I'm trying to illustrate that if I use a different model and controller name for `$useTable = 'catalog_product_entity'`, things work as they're supposed to, while if I use a similar model/controller name with `$useTable = 'catalog_product_entity'`, CakePHP thinks the model name is supposed to be the camelCase of table specified to be used.

Comment: @AD7six: I removed the confusing part. It was unnecessary.